# How to evaluate chirp transform in O(nlgn) time?

Tags: polynomials, fourier-analysis, convolution, fourier-transform, fast-fourier-transform

The question says to evaluate chirp transform in O(nlgn) time using the equation in the hint. But I'm unable to get any idea on how to prove the chirp transform from it. Any help is appreciated.
[image]

Comment: Well, the hint says it. How would you do a convolution quickly?

Comment: $y_k$ doesn't seem to depend on $k$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews : they meant $y_k = \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} a_j z^{kj}$